# How do you model a Center Turning Lane in AnyLogic

Tags: model, anylogic, traffic

I am trying to model [this intersection](https://www.google.com/maps/@30.4171068,-81.6655441,189m/data=!3m1!1e3) which has a two lane road with a center turning lane. Traffic in this lane can go either direction, but is supposed to only be used for turning. I suppose I could put a lane going in one direction, but that's not the true way the lane is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current limitations (or features?) of the Car library do not allow using one lane for two directions. I use the other movement types with nodes and paths as a workaround. Like this:

[image]